# Lua(La)TeX does not kern at discretionaries following ligatures?

Tags: luatex, kerning

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[usenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "testkern",
        type = "kern",
        data = {
            ["O"] = { ["f_f_i"] = 500 },
            ["f_f_i"] = { ["c"] = 500 },
            ["r"] = { ["fl"] = 500 },
        },
    }
}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[RawFeature = +testkern]
\usepackage{showhyphenation}
\usepackage{showkerning}

\begin{document}
Office\par
Official\par
Butterfly
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fixed at source, I think https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2022-December/006712.html (not tested)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmm... "LuaTeX does not insert kerning between hyphens and characters before discretionary hyphens if the hyphen was inserted automatically." –‎ I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean. (At least, I can't find that there is a general issue with kerning between characters and discretionary hyphens.) - Are you able to explain it to me?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Besides, how can I download the indicated source files to test if the issue described above is fixed by them?

Comment: You are not clear what you expect [I get one more green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfoBU.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. – How exactly did you do it?

Comment: I have checked out a full texlive source repository and have a full configure/automake compile chain set up, I compiled a luatex a couple of weeks ago. But as shown above I get no red triangles but an extra green kern using `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.1 (TeX Live 2023/dev)
Development id: 7549`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 1) Unfortunately I still don't understand what that means. 2) I don't even know where I can find the latest LuaTeX source code. The link on the LuaTeX website is broken (!?) and the other repositories I can find on the web don't appear to have been updated for months. 3) Does what you write mean that the output in your screenshot will be the future behaviour of LuaTeX? 4) I use MikTeX which currently has LuaTeX 1.15.1. 5) That the hyphenation markers disappear is quite surprising … I'm scratching my head.

Comment: 6) Most importantly: What is the bottom line here, given that I want the issue to be resolved in my production use of LuaTeX? What can I do or how long do I have to wait? (I guess for now I might just write myself a Lua function that takes care of this.)

Comment: if you have texlive the binaries won't update until tl2023, usually around april, miktex likely sooner I used the github mirror of texlive svn so  https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source which has been updated within last few hours.